# JEST unit testcase - beginner and facing issues

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

**im trying to to convert below code snippet to JEST unit testing but its throwing error please help me out in resolving it**
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import IdleTimer from 'react-idle-timer';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import Alert from '../components/Alert';
import NoAccess from '../pages/NoAccess';
import { GQL } from '../services/GQL';
import { IdleTimeOutModal } from './IdleTimeoutModal';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../App.scss';
import '../assets/css/loader.scss';
import AuthenticatedRoute from '../guards/AuthenticatedRoute';
import auth from '../services/Auth';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

```
class Layout extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
        this.state = {
            timeout:1000 * 900 * 1,
            showModal: false,
            userLoggedIn: window.localStorage.getItem('loginUser'),
            isTimedOut: false,
            
        }

        this.idleTimer = null
        this.onAction = this._onAction.bind(this)
        this.onActive = this._onActive.bind(this)
        this.onIdle = this._onIdle.bind(this)
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)
        this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this)
    }

    _onAction(e) {
      // console.log('user did something', e)
      this.setState({isTimedOut: false})
    }
   
    _onActive(e) {
      // console.log('user is active', e)
      this.setState({isTimedOut: false})
    }
   
    _onIdle(e) {
      // console.log('user is idle', e)
      const isTimedOut = this.state.isTimedOut
      if (isTimedOut) {
        this.setState({showModal: false})
         window.localStorage.setItem('loginUser', 'false');
      } else {
        this.setState({showModal: true})
        this.idleTimer.reset();
        this.setState({isTimedOut: true})
      }
      
    }

    handleClose() {
      this.setState({showModal: false})
    }

    handleLogout() {
      this.setState({showModal: false})
      auth.signout();
    }

    render(){
      // console.log(window.location)
      const {match} = window.location.href;
      // const { match } = this.location
      return(
        <>
          <IdleTimer
            ref={ref => { this.idleTimer = ref }}
            element={document}
            onActive={this.onActive}
            onIdle={this.onIdle}
            onAction={this.onAction}
            debounce={250}
            timeout={this.state.timeout} />

            <div className="">
            <ApolloProvider client={GQL}>
                <Router>
                  <Switch>
                    {/* <Route component={NoAccess} path="/no-access" exact={true} /> */}
                    <AuthenticatedRoute  path={`${window.location.pathname}`} component={Dashboard} />
                  </Switch>
                </Router>
                {/* <Loader isOpen={loader.isLoading} /> */}
                {/* <Alert /> */}
            </ApolloProvider>
                <IdleTimeOutModal 
                    showModal={this.state.showModal} 
                    handleClose={this.handleClose}
                    handleLogout={this.handleLogout}
                />
            </div>
        </>
      )
   }

 }

***JEST throwing error while converting to JEST -     ShallowWrapper::state() can only be called on class components 
jest help***

export default connect((props) =>({
  match: props.uiel.isRequired,
  history: props.uiel.isRequired
}))(Layout);     

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Layout from './Layout';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import { IdleTimeOutModal } from './IdleTimeoutModal';
import { wrap } from 'module';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

const mockStore = configureMockStore();

let handleLogout:any;
let showModal: any;
let handleClose:any;
let remainingTime:any;
let _onAction:any;
let _onIdle:any;
let _onActive:any;
let idleTimer:any;

describe("Render Layout Component", ()=>{
  let store;
  let wrapperlayout:any;
  beforeEach(()=>{
    store = mockStore({
      loader: false
    });
    wrapperlayout = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
       <Layout />
      </Provider>
    );
  });
  it('should render the value of color', () => {
    wrapperlayout.setProps({ timeout:1000 * 900 * 1 });
    wrapperlayout.setProps({ showModal: false });
    wrapperlayout.setProps({ userLoggedIn: window.localStorage.getItem('loginUser') });
    wrapperlayout.setProps({ isTimedOut: false });
    //expect(wrapper.state('color')).toEqual('transparent');
 });
 it("should increment index - function test", () => {
  //const app = shallow(<Normal />);
  expect(wrapperlayout.state("isTimedOut")).toEqual('false');
  wrapperlayout.instance()._onAction();
  expect(wrapperlayout.state("isTimedOut")).toEqual('false');
});
  test("Render Modal Layout", ()=>{
    expect(wrapperlayout.exists()).toBe(true);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Please help me in converting above code snippet to JEST

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I just wanted to point out that your code here is posted as plain text and is hard for us to read. Please format your code to make it more readable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Stack Overflow editing help to guide you on how you can format your codes. Goodluck :D